# Identifying if a given statement is a correct one or not

Tags: logic

$∀x A \vdash A$ is this a correct statement? 
I am not sure how to approach this. As for interpreting, it normally would be like. 
If for all x A is true then A is true So this seems a correct statement

Comment: The given meta sentence does make sense.  Possibly (though not necessarily), the entailment (on the right of the turnstile) contains a free variable where the assumption (on the left of the turnstile) does not.

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Answer (score 0):

If your notation is not mistaken and if x does not occur freely in A on both sides, then by simple semantic informal reasoning, this entailment is trivially true. If you want formal proof, you need ∀ Elimination rule first, and then use A→A Reiteration rule. If you want the other way around, you only need ∀ Introduction rule introducing an arbitrary constant from its background domain of discourse as a subproof step in your formal derivation.